# how to force await to continue in same caller thread in Console application

Tags: .net, async-await, task-parallel-library, threadpool

I am writing a .Net Console application in C#.

I need to convert the Event based Threaded call to async method.

For example :

```
public class WorkerClass
    {
        public EventHandler Progress;
        public EventHandler Finished;
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            Thread td = new Thread(Start);
            td.Name = "Worker Thread";
            td.Start();
        }

        private void Start()
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < 10)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                i++;
                var progress = i * 10;
                Progress?.Invoke((object)progress, null);
            }
            Finished?.Invoke(null, null);
        }
    }



    Class MyMainClass
            {
                private static WorkerClass myWorkerClass;
                static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                    myWorkerClass = new WorkerClass();
                    RunAsynchronously(null);
                }
                private async void RunAsynchronously(EventHandler progress)        
                {           
                    //Main Thread Call

                    await DoSomethingAsync(progress);

                    //Resume after worker finished is not in main thread? :(
                    //Needed main thread to continue
                }
                private Task<int> DoSomethingAsync(EventHandler progress)
                {
                    var completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

                    EventHandler Progress = null;
                    EventHandler Finished = null;

                    Finished = (o, e) =>
                    {
                        myWorkerClass.Finished -= Finished;
                        myWorkerClass.Progress -= Progress;
                        completionSource.SetResult(100);
                    };

                    Progress = (o, e) => { progress?.Invoke(o, e); };

                    myWorkerClass.Finished += Finished;
                    myWorkerClass.Progress += Progress;

                    myWorkerClass.DoSomething();            

                    return completionSource.Task;
                }
            }
```

Due to some limitation i need the main thread to continue, 
However after await resumes the in RunAsynchronously method , the current thread is something different than main thread (or the thread that called await).

I know this behaviour will automatically work if the caller is UI thread, but in my case it is console application and i dont have UI.

Please suggest solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is `DoSomethingAsync(EventHandler progress)` async at all? It's just a classic synchronous method. Where's your `static void Main()` ? Which language version are you on?

Comment: Its just a sample code , consider static void Main() in MyMainClass class, which further calls DoSomethingAsync(null);  

For Example:

static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            myWorkerClass = new WorkerClass();
            RunAsynchronously(null);
        }

Comment: Can you confirm that this actually works (be it on the wrong thread)? I'd expect the application  to terminate at `await DoSomethingAsync...`.

Comment: I am using C# 7.0 version. DoSomethingAsyc(EventHandler progress) is async because of two reasons 1) It will be performing long running operation so i don't want to block the thread . 2) I want to convert Event based asynchronous pattern to one single API call.

Comment: @ Haukinger Yes it is actually running fine , the only problem is after await the continuation is in wrong thread in case of Console application , If we use WinForm or WPF then even the continuation is in Correct thread i.e UI thread.

Comment: @Haukinger  Please dont be confused by ** before DoSomethingAsync, I tried making them bold and Editor added ** to it :P

Comment: When I try this, I get one thread id and "done", but the program's not waiting for the delay: internal class Program
{
 static void Main( string[] args )
 {
  DoSomethingAsync();
  Console.WriteLine( "done" );
 }

 private static async void DoSomethingAsync()
 {
  Console.WriteLine( Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId );
  await Task.Delay( 3000 );
  Console.WriteLine( Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId );
 }
}

Comment: Here's the explanation and solution for this case: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/01/20/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/

Comment: Or use an async main in the first place (that's why I asked for c# version) - but he doesn't want to await in main, obviously

Answer (score 1):

I feel like you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what to expect from a console application and the threading model of a .NET application.

A console application runs until its entry thread completes execution of the `Main` method. This means you either keep the thread busy doing work, or you block the thread until another signal unblocks it and allows the method to exit. It's a very simple construct designed to allow you to start your application, do some work, then exit when you're done. It means the thread is never "free" to do other work; you can't schedule a task to continue on this thread without completely changing the work-scheduling model to a much more sophisticated one.

In a UI-based application, your application follows a much more complex model. Instead of the application doing some work, then exiting, instead the main thread is asked to pump a message queue, doing work based on messages received and only exiting when it receives a "quit" message. This model takes a single thread and gives it a queue of work to do, each piece of work signalled by a message. This is what allows you to have a `Task` resume on the UI thread.

---

This kind of confusion is why the `async void` pattern is generally considered an anti-pattern, and certainly why it is only acceptable to use in applications with a UI. The application only works correctly because of a very specific task-scheduling model. Any other model causes this construct to break, swallowing exceptions and making it impossible to know when work has completed.